# How to query a database from view - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have query that runs in the controller:

```
$data['query'] = $this->Member->select_sql($id);    
$this->load->view('myform');
```

and then outputs data in the view:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row):
   echo $row->post_title;
   echo $row->post_user_id;
endforeach;
```

So this outputs me a list of posts made by a user. Now I would like to run one more query that would for each post loop through my user table and output user information next to each post. (I dont want to select data from a view or joint those 2 tables at this time in MySQL)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is such a good idea - the whole point of MVC is to enforce clean code structure. You're not supposed to have business logic in views.

Comment: this is only for a testing purpose, to concerning performance. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Veeti There is nothing wrong with calling upon the Model from the View. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973221/can-i-call-a-model-from-a-view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject the database adapter or appropriate table object into the View.

From your code above, I'd assume this would be

```
$data['userModel'] = $this->User;
```

Then use it from there to run your query, e.g.

```
$user = $userModel->select_sql($row->post_user_id);
```

Answer (score 7):

Although it is not a good practice, the "cleanest" approach would be as follows:

- Grab the CI instance in the View
- Load the model containing your desired data extraction query functions
- Run the function from the model in the view

So, in the view:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('modelname');
$result = $CI->modelname->functionname();
var_dump($result);
```

Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
<?php 
                        $qryd='select * from '.$tbname.'';
                        $queryd = $this->db->query($qryd);
                        $resultset = $queryd->result_array();
                    ?>
```