# Using actionHelper without returning layout in output

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

I call an action helper in one of my views using the following code

```
echo $this->action('foo', 'bar');
```

The fooAction in the barController does its thing and outputs a list of pages. However, the list has the layout in the output again, which is mightily irritating. If I disable the layout in the fooAction, this causes layout to be completely disabled on the live side, as well.

I'm vexed. I could just create a view helper, and there are many ways around this, but out of curiousity I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ZF Reference Guide on Action ViewHelper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

> The API for the Action view helper follows that of most MVC components that invoke controller actions: `action($action, $controller, $module = null, array $params = array())`. `$action` and `$controller`  are required; if no module is specified, the default module is assumed.

Modify your controller to accept a param that controls whether the action should disable the layout. When using the action helper, pass this control flag.

On a sidenote: using the Action ViewHelper is considered bad practise as it will go through the entire dispatch process again and this will slow down your app. If possible, [try to access the model directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973221/can-i-call-a-model-from-a-view/1973695#1973695).