# CakePHP foreach loop in view to call function

Tags: arrays, function, cakephp, foreach

I have a normal foreach call `foreach($users as $k=>$user):` in my view.

However in this loop i need to call a function from either my controller or model (not sure where), that goes and runs a few other web based checks and returns an array as a result...

How do i call a function from within my foreach loop inside my view? Or is there another way i am unaware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I call a Model from a View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973221/can-i-call-a-model-from-a-view) and [many similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cakephp+call+model+from+view&submit=search). `foreach` is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are breaking MVC. You should have all the data readied in the controller, before rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a basic MVC (Model, View, Controller) concept. If you call a controller or model from a view, you do something they don't wan't let you do.

It's a better practice to create a [helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1095/Helpers), which you can access from the view.