# How to change date format of a templated string inside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

I have a templated string `{{posted}}` in the below HTML code. The date is extracted from XML and is of the format `Y-m-d` like `2012-03-15`.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td>{{posted}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

So now I want to display this date as 15 Mar 2012. So what should I do for this. I tried with Javascript and PHP but I get date as `01 Jan 1970` How can I display the date as 15 Mar 2012. Is there any Jquery plugin or Javascript function.

Comment: What template script is this?

Comment: @Glavić Handle bar template is used

Comment: @Glavić Can you tell me why template makes differnece

Comment: You should know the answer for that, it was your choice too work with template engine. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/731743/67332 . I was just wondering what template engine is this, maybe it has some build in feature to convert dates or something.

Comment: @Glavić I should have known all this things. But, it was developed by some one. So you say I cannot do anything with this in PHP.

Comment: I never said that ;) You should learn how to debug input data, and what basic functions in php accept as parameters. If you learn that (few minutes of your time), I think you would never ask this question, because you would see the problem a mile/kilometer away. Cos, if input was really only `2013-03-15`, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20700803/67332) would work 100%.

Comment: Ya... As you said I tried for that answer, but what is happening is strtotime is returning false and hence displays date as `01-Jan 1970`

Comment: Have you figure it out, in what cases does `strtotime()` returns `false` ?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this...

```
<?php
$pubDt = '2012-03-15';
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $pubDt);
echo $newPubdate = $date->format('j M Y'); // "prints" 15 Mar 2012
```

Comment: I get this error when I add this - `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

Comment: I copy pasted from here.. https://eval.in/81412 . Maybe your $date is coming in someother format. Can you `var_dump` your date

Comment: Yes shankar  I will do it

Comment: Can you replace `Y-m-d` with `Y-m-j` and let me know ?

Comment: var_dump gave me this output - `string(10) "2013-11-27" `

Comment: Can you try with `Y-n-j` ? You can refer this table to suit the needs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43577/discussion-between-user3004356-and-shankar-damodaran)

Answer (score 0):

In php you can try this

```
$date = '2012-03-15';
echo date('d M Y',strtotime($date));
```

Comment: `                                   <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td> <?php $date = '{{posted}}';</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>  
echo date('d M Y',strtotime($date));?>` - it returns date as 01 Jan 1970