# Smarty - Export txt files from TPL

Tags: php, smarty

I basically have this code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>{$root.page.contentgroup.Directory[0]}</td>
<td>{$root.page.contentgroup.Title[0]}</td>
<td>{$root.page.contentgroup.Description[0]}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would love to add a button, and when I click it, it generate 3 txt files.
When the script generate the txt file, it should locate them according to {$root.page.contentgroup.Directory[0]}.
For example:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>mydirectory</td> {**directory.txt**}
<td>mytitle</td> {**title.txt**}
<td>mydescription</td> {**description.txt**}
</tr> 
</table>
[SUBMIT]
```

When I click submit, the script generate the 3 txt files and locate them on

```
mysite/folder/{$root.page.contentgroup.Directory[0]}/directory.txt
mysite/folder/{$root.page.contentgroup.Directory[0]}/title.txt
mysite/folder/{$root.page.contentgroup.Directory[0]}/description.txt
```

what is the better way to do it? I can use only smarty functions (((

Thank you

Comment: You should do it in PHP and not in Smarty

Answer (score 0):

This must be implemented with `php`. Smarty is a template engine, and must be used **only for presentation.** (Or even better *-my opinion-* don't use a template engine at all. An opinion based question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731743/php-vs-template-engine).)

If you want **badly** to do things **really bad**, you may use the `{php}` tag that allows php code to be embeded inside smarty's `.tpl` files.

```
{php}
   // including a php script directly from the template.
   include('/path/to/your_file_generation_script.php');
{/php}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl